# Target iOS with Flutter, 8.0 or more?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I am building an iOS app on Flutter. I don't know which Target iOS I have to choose before archiving my app on Xcode (in order to send it to the App Store). It seems to be iOS 8.0 by default. Do I have to keep it 8.0 or should I increase the iOS version to 12.4 or 13.5 ?
Is there any differents ? (Beside the fact that if I put 13.5 as iOS target, old iPhones on 12.4 will not be able to open my app).

Thank you for your time ! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference is what features are available. If you target an App for iOS 8.0 you cannot use features that came with iOS 10.0 (Because it won't be available for iOS 8 and 9).

In other words. Target the lowest version you can, otherwise you just cut off people that you don't need to from using your App.

Comment: Yes thank you, I just see that the module firestore is not available in iOS 8 and 10, but available for iOS 12.4

Comment: @LeursDimitri No Problem, feel free to accept the answer if you feel like it helped.